# SAP GUI Scripting Close pop up window python

Tags: python, sap-gui

I'm trying to close a pop up window in python scripting for SAP GUI.

Here's my code and I'm trying to close a pop up window (if appears) at the end of the code.

```
for index, row in data.iterrows():

    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEINA-LIFNR").text = row.SAP_Local_Vendor_ID
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEINA-MATNR").text = row.Part_No
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEINE-EKORG").text = "1000"
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEINE-WERKS").text = "0695"
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEINE-WERKS").setFocus
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtEINE-WERKS").caretPosition = 4
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[0]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[1]/btn[8]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[7]").press()
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRV13A-DATAB").text = "12/01/2022"
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMV13ATCTRL_D0201/txtKONP-KBETR[2,0]").text = row.Unit_by_PER
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMV13ATCTRL_D0201/txtKONP-KPEIN[4,0]").text = "1000"
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMV13ATCTRL_D0201/txtKONP-KPEIN[4,0]").setFocus
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tblSAPMV13ATCTRL_D0201/txtKONP-KPEIN[4,0]").caretPosition = 5
    self.session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/btn[11]").press()
    if (session.ActiveWindow.Name == "wnd[1]"):
        self.session.findById("wnd[1]/tbar[0]/btn[5]").press()
```

I've tried various ifs statements but its not working. can you help me ?

Comment: give the screenshot of the popup. SAP uses several popups for different events, and they brings different behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it will work:

```
if not session.FindById("wnd[1]", False) == None:
```

Comment: **Answer is unclear**
As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). You risk your answer being deleted because it is too vague. Where and how does this address the question?